# error connecting to rabbitmq using easynetq driver

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I was connecting to RabbitMQ with easynetQ driver without any issues when all of a sudden. I started getting this error

System.ArgumentException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.dll
Additional information: None of the discovered or specified addresses match the socket address family.

Why am i not able to find the rabbit mq server all of a sudden. What would be the root cause of this issue. No network configuration has changed.

Comment: It seems the exception is always thrown whenever the easynetq bus is created. i had put break on exception which lead me to believe an error was present,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had the Break on exception setting turned on leading me to believe that the exception was coming through my code. The driver connects to the rabbitmq after the error is thrown.